# Form tag and AJAX request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I made a simple page with a couple of radio buttons and a textfield as an exercise:

```
<html>
   ...

    Student list: <input type="radio"   name="list" value="students">
    Lession list: <input type="radio"   name="list" value="lessons">

    <h2>Type the course code:</h2> 

    Code: <input type="text" name="code" id="code">
   <input type="submit" id="submit">
</html>
```

And I added a listener to the button through Javascript.

Now via Javascript I collect the data from the various input fields, and pack them in a request:

```
function prepareRequest(req) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("list");
    var value;
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {            
            value = radios[i].value;
        }
    }
    var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
    var url = "../AjaxServlet?value="+value+"&code="+code;
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send();
}
```

I call my servlet through Javascript, GET my data, and then handle the response.

If I wanted to do this with "pure" HTML, I'd enclose those inputs in a FORM tag, like this:

```
<form action="../AjaxServlet" method="get">
    ...
   <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Now when I hit submit, the servlet is called "through" the form, which sends all the data it collected automatically. Of course this is  synchronous and the page has to reload/redirect.

What I'm wondering is, with AJAX, is there any need for the form tag? What I did seemed intuitive enough, get the input elements from the DOM, extract the data and then pack them in a request manually. Is this right or wrong? Is there a standard or better way to do this?

Comment: It's mostly the matter of taste, but if you you use submit button, you'll have to override default behavior onclick\enter_key.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was wondering about that too. Would you suggest using some other element as a "button"? Like styling a div and adding an onclick listener to it?

Comment: your question is too broad. my take is using javascript when required. keep it at minimum. do you need special validation or actions before or after posting your request? use javascript.

Comment: Not in this case, I just want to show the content of the response without reloading the page, which requires AJAX.

Comment: [Yes, you need a form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes jQuery use (which your question is not, kudos).

One of the benefits of using the `form` tag is the serialization of the form. Allowing for a cleaner approach of passing form data to your processing page.

It's also a bit cleaner (IMO) for form validation. Obviously there are many ways to validate form input but you can easily pass the form object and search for required elements having a valid value.

Adapted from [Ajax and Forms](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ajax-and-forms/) on Learn.jQuery.com.

Although I would agree with celerno do what you need to do, but keep it at a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

if you use form tag then your current web page will be change form tag page

example

```
in blabla.html
    <form action=/api/send_hi method="POST"> 
        <button name="ID" value="hi">
    </form>
```

click button then current web page will be blabla/api/send_hi.html and result is
{ID: 'hi'}

if you use ajax then your current web page will not be change form tag page

```
in blabla.html
    blabla ~~~
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function hi(){
            $.ajax({
                     url: '/api/send_hi',
                     method: 'POST',
                     dataType: 'JSON',
                     data: {'ID': 'hi'},
                     async: false
             }).done(function(data)){ // do if ajax communication success}
    </script>
    <body>
          <button onclick=hi()>
    </body>
```

this result is same as form tag result but current web page is not changed
still blabla.html not /api/send_hi.html